# Is there an ATM at Tel-Aviv airport?

Tags: money, israel, atms, tlv

A few years ago I saw money changers (costly) in the Tel Aviv airport but not a money machine (kash-po-mat).  Is there a money machine at the airport? If so, where is it and does it charge the same as other money machines in the country or is there any special fee for the airport?

Comment: First time I read "money machine", I envisioned a machine that prints money on demand :)

Comment: ATM's are pretty much ubiquitous in Tel Aviv and surrounding areas.  And that include within Ben Gurion where you'll find plenty of them within the arrivals hall and elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From both personal experience and [Internet forums](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293984-i3332-k5956930-Is_there_an_ATM_or_money_changer_at_Ben_Gurion_airport-Tel_Aviv_Tel_Aviv_District.html), there are multiple ATMs at Ben Gurion airport in Tel-Aviv. I've even managed to find a photo of one ATM in the arrivals zone:

[image]

Comment: Interesting that in addition to Hebrew and English, Arabic is also used on signage.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Hebrew and Arabic are official languages in Israel, not English!

Comment: does it charge the same as other money machines in the country or is there any special fee for the airport?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC not sure about your bank, but my card wasn't charged any extra fees at any of the ATMs.

Answer (score 2):

There are several in the departures area, they will allow you to withdraw Shekels, Dollars (USD) or Euros.

Look down the "B" and "C" wings about a 2 minute walk from the main area.

Comment: does it charge the same as other money machines in the country or is there any special fee for the airport?

Comment: I don't know, sorry but I think it will tell you

Answer (score -2):

***Tel Aviv Ben Gurion Airport exchange offices are located in the Arrivals Hall.***

Use our Tel Aviv Ben Gurion Airport Currency Exchange Calculator to estimate Tel Aviv Ben Gurion Airport foreign exchange rates on the Israeli Shekel (ILS) currency.

***Locations of TLV Tel Aviv Ben Gurion Airport ATM & Cash Machines***

The currency in use at the Tel Aviv Ben Gurion Airport in Israel is the Israeli Shekel, abbreviated as ILS.

The Tel Aviv Ben Gurion Airport ATM or Tel Aviv Ben Gurion Airport cash machine locations may be found:

Tel Aviv Ben Gurion Airport ATM's are located in the Arrivals Hall.

Comment: Where did you quote this from?